# How to get data from an array inside an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

My data structure is as follows

```
var processArray = [];
for(i = 0;i < someProcess.length;i++){
     processArray.push({
        id: i,
        processName: someProcess[i],
        processType: someType[i]
     });
}
//someProcess and someType are arrays from database.
```

I use this processArray to populate a HTML list. After some operations by the user (eg:- adding more data or deleting some), I need to extract all processName from processArray and store them in another array, lets say newProcessList. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var processArray = [];
for(i = 0;i < someProcess.length;i++){
     processArray.push({
        id: i,
        processName: someProcess[i],
        processType: someType[i]
     });
}

var newProcessList = processArray.map(function(el){

          return el.processName;

});
```